# Get Fritz box incoming caller id using Java

Tags: java, sip, fritzbox

Need to get incoming caller id through 'Fritz Box' enabled router using java. should to be real-time caller id gathering.

This will be from any PC connected to the router via LAN. When call coming to the phone, then i need to get the caller informations.

Comment: you need to get it... from where? Where will the Java application be running?

Comment: It running as standalone application and connected to the router via LAN. When call coming to the phone, then i need to get the caller informations

Comment: See the API documentation: https://avm.de/service/schnittstellen/ The web page is in German, the documents are usually in English. However I do not remember an API that would allow you real-time monitoring of telephone calls.